# Multiple success messages from SQL Server Update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, message

I have the following query that SHOULD update 716 records:

```
USE db1
GO

UPDATE SAMP
SET flag1 = 'F', flag2 = 'F'

FROM samp INNER JOIN result ON samp.samp_num = result.samp_num
WHERE result.status != 'X'
    AND result.name = 'compound'
    AND result.alias = '1313'
    AND sample.standard = 'F'
    AND sample.flag2 = 'T';
```

However, when this query is run on a SQL Server 2005 database from a query window in SSMS, I get the following THREE messages:

```
716 row(s) affected
10814 row(s) affected
716 row(s) affected
```

So WHY am I getting 3 messages (instead of the normal one for a single update statement) and WHAT does the 10814 likely refer to?  This is a production database I need to update so I don't want to commit these changes without knowing the answer :-)  Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is likely caused by a trigger on the [samp] table. If you go to Query -> Query Options -> Execution -> Advanced and check SET STATISTICS IO, you will see which other tables are being updated when you run the query.

Comment: Thanks man, that does explain what is going on.  I didn't design the database, so didn't know there was a trigger on the table. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the object browser in SSMS to look for the triggers. Open the Tables Node, find the table, open the table node and then open the triggers. The nice thing about this method is that you can script the trigger to a new query window and see what the trigger is doing.

Answer (score -1):

It's probably because you have one trigger in your table.
This command will show you what is happening.

SET STATISTICS IO { ON | OFF }

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184361.aspx

Comment: This is hardly any different from the accepted answer posted 2 years ago.